# Can't get the algebra (quadratic formula) to work

Tags: python, calculator, algebra, quadratic

I have been working on very simple calculator with a few functions for a computer science course, and of the calculators functions is solving quadratic equations. I have tried to make it work but I get this error:[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FznZI.png). I don't understand why it does this since I input all of it.[screenshot of input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3zMf.png). If anyone could help that would be great.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
from functools import partial

#defining functions for operations
#Addition
def add_result(label_result, n1, n2):
    num1 = (n1.get())
    num2 = (n2.get())
    result = float(num1)+float(num2)
    label_result.config(text="Result is %d" % result)
    return

#Multiplication
def mult_result(label_result, n1, n2):
    num1 = (n1.get())
    num2 = (n2.get())
    result = float(num1)*float(num2)
    label_result.config(text="Result is %d" % result)
    return

#Subtraction
def sub_result(label_result, n1, n2):
    num1 = (n1.get())
    num2 = (n2.get())
    result = float(num1)-float(num2)
    label_result.config(text="Result is %d" % result)
    return

#Division
def div_result(label_result, n1, n2):
    num1 = (n1.get())
    num2 = (n2.get())
    result = float(num1)/float(num2)
    label_result.config(text="Result is %d" % result)
    return

#SquareRoot
def sqrt_result(label_result, n1):
    num1 = (n1.get())
    result = math.sqrt(float(num1))
    label_result.config(text="Result is %d" % result)
    return

def algebraMode(label_result, n1, n2, n3):
    num1 = (n1.get())
    num2 = (n2.get())
    num3 = (n3.get())
    sol1 = (-float(num2) + math.sqrt(float(num2)**2 - 4*float(num1)*float(num3))) / (2 * float(num1))
    sol2 = (-float(num2) - math.sqrt(float(num2)**2 - 4*float(num1)*float(num3))) / (2 * float(num1))
    label_result.config(text="The solutions are %d" % sol1 + " %d" % sol2)
    return



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('450x170+100+200')
root.title('Simple Calculator')

number1 = tk.StringVar()
number2 = tk.StringVar()
number3 = tk.StringVar()


labelNum1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter a number").grid(row=2, column=1)
labelNum2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter another number").grid(row=3, column=1)
labelNum3 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter another number (Algebra Mode Only)").grid(row=4, column=1)
labelResult = tk.Label(root)
labelResult.grid(row=7, column=2)

entryNum1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number1).grid(row=2, column=2)
entryNum2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number2).grid(row=3, column=2)
entryNum3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number3).grid(row=4, column=2)
add_result = partial(add_result, labelResult, number1, number2)
mult_result = partial(mult_result, labelResult, number1, number2)
sub_result = partial(sub_result, labelResult, number1, number2)
div_result = partial(div_result, labelResult, number1, number2)
sqrt_result = partial(sqrt_result, labelResult, number1, number2)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Add", command=add_result).grid(row=1, column=0)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Multiply", comma=mult_result).grid(row=2, column=0)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Subtract", command=sub_result).grid(row=3, column=0)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Divide", command=div_result).grid(row=4, column=0)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Square Root", command=sqrt_result).grid(row=5, column=0)
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Algebra", command=algebraMode).grid(row=6, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: post the code, not screenshots

Comment: the code is there

Comment: looks like you are missing the partial definition: `algebraMode = partial(albegraMode, labelResult, number1, number2, number3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follow code below `sqrt_result = partial(....)`:

```
algebraMode = partial(algebraMode, labelResult, number1, number2, number3)
```

Then it should work as your others do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel a little dumb for not seeing that haha.